# Why did Peaches' mom hang on the tree?

Tags: plot-explanation, ice-age-4

In the middle of the movie [*Ice Age: Continental Drift*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1667889/) Peaches' mom asked Peaches to go to sleep. Then, she hung on the tree. This particular scene was quite strange and confused me pretty badly, because she's a mammoth, **why did she hang on the tree like that?**

Further, I've only watched the Ice Age3 and Ice Age4. Did I miss anything? Did they show any scene towards Peaches' mom's strange behavior in the previous parts?

Comment: peaches and ellie are half possum but manny is whole mammoth

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Ice Age 2, when Elle was first introduced, she thought she was a possum, thus hanging upside down in a tree to sleep. Some of her habits were taught to Peaches, thus the girl sleeping upside down.

In Ice Age 4, there was a line of dialogue from Peaches about being half possum.  this came from the idea that Elle still believes herself to be a possum, but that Peaches' dad is a mammoth.

Comment: Thanks @DForck42, but are you sure there was a line in ice age4 about this half possum? because i've to re-watch the movie.

Comment: @VijinPaulraj yes, there is a line spoken about being half-possum.  I don't remember the entire line though but i believe it is said by Peaches.

Answer (score 2):

In ICE AGE 2, Ellie is introduced as having been living with the Possums. She is led to believe that she is *also* a Possum ( Yes,it is true that she thinks she is one of them.Watch the movie). There are quite a few scenes dedicated to Manny trying to convince Ellie that she is actually a mammoth and not a possum.

/Possums sleep by hanging upside down from a tree using their tails as a hook.

This is why Peaches believes that she is half-possum and she hangs upside down from a tree.